# Python (pandas)- choosing a specific column in an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, import

I'm a beginner in **Python(3.11.3)** w/ **pandas** and I have been tackling with this issue for hours

I suspect the issue is caused by `selected_A = random.sample(list(df['A']), 80)` it seems like my code cannot find "A" column in the excel file but I'm not sure how to fix it. :/

Suggestions are welcome!

## **Goal:**

to select 80 cells randomly from "A" column in "OriginalPairedList.xlsx" and save the selected cells in column D.

## **current issue:**

the current code cannot select/read a column (A) I want from my excel file(OriginalPairedList.xlsx) and therefore unable to execute.

## **My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import random
os.chdir("TLBX_experiment/pilotZone/expicture")

# read excel file
df = pd.read_excel("OriginalPairedList.xlsx")

# select 80 cells from column A and store in column D
selected_A = random.sample(list(df['A']), 80)
df['D'] = selected_A
```

## **Terminal message:**

```
jamesabcd@PodeMacBook-Pro Desktop % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11 /Users/jamesabcd/Desktop/TLBX_exp
eriment/pilotZone/expicture/selectAB4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3652, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'A'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesabcd/Desktop/TLBX_experiment/pilotZone/expicture/selectAB4.py", line 10, in <module>
    selected_A = random.sample(list(df['A']), 80)
                                    ~~^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3654, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'A'
```

I tried print (random.sample(list(df['A']))) but it's not functioning.

```
jamesabcd@PodeMacBook-Pro Desktop % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11 /Users/jamesabcd/Desktop/TLBX_exp
eriment/pilotZone/expicture/selectAB4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3652, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'A'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesabcd/Desktop/TLBX_experiment/pilotZone/expicture/selectAB4.py", line 10, in <module>
    selected_A = random.sample(list(df['A']), 80)
                                    ~~^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3654, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'A'
```

Comment: A KeyError means that the column in question ('A') does not exist. You can do ```print(df.columns)``` to see a list of all the columns present in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stressed, the solution is quite simple: giving column(s) a name(s) can solve this issue:

Before columns:

[image]

After columns (named):

[image]